# StarCraft II does not install on Mac OS X with FileVault

Tags: starcraft-2, macos

I have the same problem as described [here](http://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100729231112AAq3uSq).

> I've installed SC2 on two systems, one
>   had this "Insert DVD" problem, the
>   other did not. I deleted all of the
>   files and re-downloaded on the system
>   asking for a DVD and it still asked
>   for the DVD. I tried moving the files
>   out of my home directory as suggested
>   by another user here and it worked.
>   Out of curiosity I tried moving the
>   files to somewhere other than
>   /Applications (I used /Users/Shared)
>   and it still worked. The one thing
>   that comes to mind as a difference
>   between my two systems is that the
>   system where I'm asked for a DVD if
>   the files are in my home directory has
>   Filevault (home directory encryption)
>   turned on. The system where I was not
>   asked for a DVD does not have
>   Filevault enabled. I wonder if the
>   installer is confused by Filevault.

I'm wondering if someone here had the same problem and found a solution to this.

Comment: You may also wish to check [Blizzard's SC2 Tech Support knowledge base](http://us.blizzard.com/support/index.xml?locale=en_US&gameId=13&rootCategoryId=3617) and/or post this in the [Blizzard SC2 Tech Support Forum](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/13438/).

Comment: Thanks. You're totally right. I just found it: http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/166496671#9

Comment: Does anyone know *why* FileVault/FV2 isn't supported? I saw speculation on the link here in the comments, but no confirmation (or why other installers don't seem to have problems with FV2...)

Answer (score 3):

I just found the solution here: http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/166496671#9

You have to either disable FileVault (not recommended) or just move the installer folder to another location, which is not encrypted.

Comment: Note that you can easily add a new unencrypted "volume" on your encrypted hard drive. This is unlike a partition and has a flexible size. Open the "Disk Utility" application and click the plus symbol above "Volume". The rest should be self-explanatory.